# Delayed save in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-execution

**Shortly**: is there a standard Rails functionality to mark a model instance for delayed save (e.g. `m.delay_save!`) and then save all marked models by single call (e.g. `DelaysManager.commit!`)?

**Verbosely**:

Consider use case:
I need to update a instance of model X in two different methods:

```
def f1
  x = get_instance_of_x
  x.a = 'A'
  x.save!
end

def f2
  x = get_instance_of_x
  x.b = 'B'
  x.save!
end
...
def g
  f1
  f2
end
```

The problem here is that g saves instance of X twice. And I want to do it once. I could move  the invocation of `save!`to method g, but in more complicated case g might not know which objects need to be saved. So I want this to look like this instead:

```
def f1
  x = get_instance_of_x
  x.a = 'A'
  x.delay :save!
end

def f2
  x = get_instance_of_x
  x.b = 'B'
  x.delay :save!
end
...
def g
  f1
  f2
  DelaysManager.commit
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def delay(*args)
    DelaysManager.delay(self, *args)
  end
end

class DelaysManager
  @@delays = []
  def self.delay(*args)
    @@delays << args
  end

  def self.commit
    @@delays.each { |object, *args| object.public_send(*args) }
    @@delays.clear
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this by collecting the modified objects into an array. Then you can just simply use save all on them. Of course, when you get the instance of an already modified object, you must check if it is present in the array.

```
def f1
  x = get_instance_of_x(params)
  x.a = 'A'
end

def f2
  x = get_instance_of_x(params)
  x.b = 'B'
end
...
def g
  @array_of_x = []
  f1
  f2
  commit
end

def get_instance_of_x(params)
  x = @array_of_x.select{|a| a.id == params[:id]} || X.find(params)
  @array_of_x << x unless @array_of_x.include(x)
  x
end

def commit
  @array_of_x.each(&:save)
end
```

Of course, you need to customize the `x = @array_of_x.select{|a| a.id == params[:id]} || X.find(params)` row to match your needs.

Comment: The idea of the sample implementation is exactly to automate maintaining of the array.

Comment: Yours saves the object as many times it is contained in the array. Thanks to the ActiveRecord, only the changes are saved, but if the same attribute is overwritten somewhere and checked somewhere else before saving, it can cause problem. And of course, it means a lot of database usage. Mine compress it a bit more, and the changed values can be used before saving. If you satisfied with your implementation then I don't really understand your question.